# Claves expuestas del servidor Firebase Cloud Messaging - Google play

Tags: android, firebase, fcm

Buen día a todos, recientemente he tenido un problema con mi aplicación en la Play Store, Google la ha estado removiendo porque la clave está expuesta, este el mensaje que recibo cada vez que remueven mi app:

Problema con tu aplicación Descubrimos que su aplicación contiene vulnerabilidades de seguridad, que pueden exponer la información del usuario o dañar el dispositivo de un usuario. Esta es una violación de la política de abuso de dispositivos y redes. Específicamente, sus aplicaciones son vulnerables a las claves expuestas del servidor Firebase Cloud Messaging. Para solucionar este problema, siga los pasos de este artículo del Centro de ayuda de Google.

Ahora que ya sabemos cuál es el problema procederé a mostrar mi código con el cual envió notificaciones a los usuarios:

```
    RequestQueue myrequest= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {

        json.put("to", TicketDatos.token); //Aqui el envio se hace al usuario que esta haciendo el proceso del pedido 
        JSONObject notificacion=new JSONObject();
        notificacion.put("titulo", "¡Hay un nuevo pedido!");
        notificacion.put("detalle","Revisa tus pedidos activos para procesar el nuevo pedido");
        notificacion.put("click_action", "NUEVOPEDIDO");
        notificacion.put("id_cliente", Login.gIdCliente);
        notificacion.put("nombre_cliente", Login.nombre);

        json.put("data",notificacion);
        String URL= "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
        JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,json,null,null){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                Map<String,String>header=new HashMap<>();
                header.put("content-type","application/json");
                header.put("authorization", DatosPrincipales.serverKey); //En esta parte es donde agrego la clave del servidor de firebase al principio tenia directamente la clave pero ahora la obtengo de la base de datos sin embargo el problema persiste

                return header;

            }
        };
        myrequest.add(request);


    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Cuando estaba aprendiendo esto de las notificaciones ya me habían advertido sobre esto que el código se debe ejecutar desde el servidor y no desde la app sin embargo mi poco conocimiento me llevo a utilizar esta forma para enviar notificaciones a los usuarios debido a que se adapta perfectamente a lo que necesitaba y de hecho siempre me había funcionado de maravilla pero lastimosamente hay una fuga de seguridad!!!

Entonces como puedo seguir utilizando este método sin obtener este problema, realmente necesito ejecutar este código dentro de la app cuando los usuarios finalizan un pedido y no he encontrado otra forma de hacerlo, si necesitan más código o más explicación por favor hacérmelo saber de antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda!!!

Comment: Actualmente es important esconder valores sensibles como Api Keys, esto para que no se obtengan mediante ingeniería inversa. Agrego el proceso para evitar el mensaje de alerta en la consola .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para evitar el siguiente mensaje de advertencia en la consola Google Play:

> Leaked GCP API Keys Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform
> (GCP) API keys. Please see this Google Help Center article for
> details.

debes definir los valores que deseas "esconder" dentro de tu archivo `gradle.properties` (si no existe, puedes crearlo)

```
JORGESYS_SERVER_KEY=key=AI9876IoaNutaEFrumoAsaAsa123An8mTRk-U
```

y definir la referencia de estos valores dentro de  `app/build.gradle`

```
android {
    ...
    ...
    defaultConfig {
    ...
    ...
    ...
        //*Defined in gradle.properties
        buildConfigField "String", "JORGESYS_SERVER_KEY", "\"$JORGESYS_SERVER_KEY\""
    }

}
```

al generar tu proyecto se generará la clase `BuildConfig` que contendrá los valores y que podrás asignar a tu aplicación al realizar la compilación.

```
//Obtiene el valor de la API Key
//header.put("authorization", DatosPrincipales.serverKey); 
header.put("authorization", BuildConfig.JORGESYS_SERVER_KEY);
```

¡Estos valores no podrán ser obtenidos al realizar "ingeniería inversa"! :-)